# Controlling a Record creation in the related list as per a picklist value

Tags: picklist, configuration

In Account object, i have a picklist field " Account status" with values as active, blacklisted.

by default, while creation its active, I want that if the value is changed to blacklisted, It shouldn't allow to create a new opportunity in the related list, and give a message that " account is blacklisted". Also, on the existing opportunity, when one entered, it shouldnt allow to edit the opp, and give teh same above message.

Can anyone plz suggest a good way to do this. I tried to use the process builder ( auto approval process), and approval process, while the value is changing , its locking the existing opp. But the drawback on my process is that,

1. Its keep allowing to create a new opp, and then unlocking it, which i dont want. from beginning it shouldn't allow and give the error message.
2. for the existing opp, its allowing to edit first time before unlocking it.
3. No error message i able to set anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Tushar for the edit, I have put in the above format actually but dont know after saving it went back the earlier format with everything in a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use validation rule to prevent new Opportunity and Edit as well. So create a Validation rule on Opportunity

```
 Account.Type == 'blacklisted'
```

So if Account Type is blacklisted then it will give you error and do not alow you to create or Edit.

Comment: Thannks Tushar. It worked